# ObjectAnimator strange behaviour while trying to pause

Tags: java, android, android-studio, objectanimator

I have a few animated objects.
I use a custom class to store their `ImageView`s and `ObjectAnimator`s

And I have a method for pausing them.
It looks pretty simple:

```
public void pause_animations(View view) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_objects; i++) {
        objects[i].animator.pause();
    }
}
```

This method being called in 2 cases:

1. As a button onClick.
2. At some random time.

When I press a button and this code runs - everything works perfectly. All objects stop their moving.
But in the second case, objects just freeze and teleport.

**UPDATE**. I have a touch listener. Every time user touches screen, a method `try_to_pause();` runs.

```
private void try_to_pause() {
    if (number_of_touches % touches_to_pause == 0) {
        pause_animations(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running the method in the UI thread for the case 2?

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana I do not use other threads. Just call this method...

Comment: Ok, but the method is running in a thread. How do you run the code at a random time? Please, add the code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the [Animator#pause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator#pause()) method, another reason may be that you **started** the animation from a different thread than main (emphasis is mine).

> Pauses a running animation. **This method should only be called on the same thread on which the animation was started.**